# Django Update Management Command

Tags: python, django, object, sql-update, command

I am trying to give the command such a way when blacklist is TRUE and active will FALSE,

But I am getting all the Blacklist TRUE and Active is FALSE.

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from wm_data_collection.models import roses


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Blacklist_TRUE  then Active_FALSE."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        roses.objects.filter(active=False).update(blacklist=True)
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have incorrect fields in filter and update methods
Shouldn't it be:

```
roses.objects.filter(blacklist=True).update(active=False)
```

Comment: Its not working , now the existing active =True is showing active = False and all the existing blacklist =Flase becomes blacklist = True.

Comment: Do you want to set blacklist=True on all users where active=False?

Comment: yes, that will work.

Comment: So that's what roses.objects.filter(active=False).update(blacklist=True) is doing. Finding all roses where active=False and setting their blacklist on True

Comment: Its taking all the Active = False and making All the Blacklist  = True

Comment: I asked "Do you want to set blacklist=True on all users where active=False?" you responsed "yes, that will work" and roses.objects.filter(active=False).update(blacklist=True) is doing exactly that

Comment: Sorry  for the miscommunication, I want to find if there is Active =True then Blacklist= False, i will not change but  I will change  when Blacklist = True then Active =False.    
          @TrueGopnik